# Limit where they have taken out the absolute value

Tags: limits

Could someone explain step by step what they are doing here. I don´t understand how it is possible to take out the absolute value in this way! As fare as I can see we are dividing by the x, or sqrt(x^2). But then -x is equal to sqrt[-x^2], how does that get to become positive I would get negative 1 and I do not understand the absolute value. I guess it has something to do with the - infinity. But I do not see it.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $x < 0$, then $|x|=-x$, so
$$\begin{align*}\sqrt{x^2+2x}-x&=\sqrt{x^2(1+(2/x))}-x\\
&=|x|\sqrt{1+(2/x)}+|x|\\
&=|x| \left ( \sqrt{1+(2/x)}+1 \right )\end{align*}$$

Answer (score 0):

Notice 
$$\sqrt{x^{2}+2x}=\sqrt{x^{2}(1+(2/x)}=|x|\sqrt{1+(2/x)}$$
and since we are taking limit as $x\rightarrow -\infty$ as we take this limit $-x=|x|$ thus we finally have
$$|x|\sqrt{1+(2/x)}+|x|=|x|\left(\sqrt{1+(2/x)}+1\right)$$